# illegal usage of identity column teradata

Tags: teradata

Getting a error while creating the volatile table illegal usage of identity column..

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE t1 (
    ID1 INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 100 NO CYCLE),
    NoSec BigInt
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, when you read the error messages it clearly indicates that IDENTITY columns are not supported for Volatile Tables.

This is a cut&paste from the Messages manual:

5784 Illegal usage of Identity Column %VSTR.

Explanation: User attempted to define an invalid identity column or use an identity column incorrectly. The error is returned if:

1) an identity column is defined as

- a) part of a composite index
- b) a join index or hash index
- c) a primary partition index
- d) a value-ordered index.

2) the input parameter of an INSERT into identity column is a using field (e.g., :F1) which is part of an expression, e.g. :F1+:F2 or :F1+2.

3) **an identity column is defined in a temporary or **volatile table**. It may
only be defined in a permanent table.

4) a USING statement contains multiple INSERT statements that insert into different
identity column tables.

5) the input parameter of an INSERT into identity column of type BY DEFAULT is a using field (e.g., :F1) that is being reused in another parameter in the insert statement, e.g. USING(F1 INT, F2 INT) INS tab(:F1,:F1);